# Evaluating the liminf and limsup

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

So I am a little bit stuck on finding the liminf and limsup of the following interval:

$$[(-1/n)^{n} , 2]$$

I know that

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = \cup^{\infty}_{n=1}(\cap^{\infty}_{j=n}A_{j})$$
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n = \cap^{\infty}_{n=1}(\cup^{\infty}_{j=n}A_{j})$$

but I do not know how to use this information to solve the question.

-Thanks!

Comment: There's an error in your last limits:: it should be $ {}_ {j=n}^\infty}A_{j} $.

Comment: @Bernard oh yeah, thank you

Comment: You have the definitions reversed - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: Not useful here, so fwiw... In the lingo of probability,  $\lim\sup A_n = \{A_n \text{ happens infinitely often}\}$, and $\lim\inf A_n = \{A_n \text{  happens almost always}\}$.  Certainly $\lim\inf A_n \subset \lim\sup A_n$.

Comment: Finally, as a hint - I would suggest you draw the (inner) union and intersections on the number line, for a few cases, say, to see what's happening.

Comment: @BenWarfield please note that Andres has corrected (swapped) your definitions of the lim sup/infs

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that $ |a_n|= |(-1/n)^n|\to 0$ is strictly decreasing thus

$$-1\le a_n\le \frac14$$

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but the problem I am having is solving the inner Union and Intersection. I just don't really understand what I am trying to do.